# Numpy array to string gives an output that if saved to a file results in a bigger file than the original image, why?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

The Operation : transforming a rgb image  numpy array to string gives an output that if saved to a file also results in a bigger file than the original image, why?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the fact that typical image formats are compressed. If you open an image using e.g. scipy.ndimage.imread, the file will be decompressed and the result will be a numpy array of size (NxMx3), where N and M are the dimensions of the image and 3 represents the [R, G, B] channels. Transforming this to a string does not perform any compression, so the result will be larger than the original file.